# What data analysis technique can I apply here?

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, multivariate-analysis

Which data analysis technique I can apply if I have personality analysis data of some sample students and if I have their performance metrics such as their grade, participation, attendance etc? I assume I can apply correlation analysis but can I apply anova or linear regression?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply just about any statistical method. ANOVA, regression of various kinds, t tests, factor analysis, cluster analysis and a bunch of others.

You are approaching this backwards.  Instead of looking at data and asking "what can I do with this?" you need to pose a problem or a question and ask "how can I use these data to solve this problem or answer this question?"